# Problem with rigging an arm of a character

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I'm trying to rig an entire arm of a character but am unable to for some reason. I started off by rigging the hand and then, tried to connect the bones of the hand to the rest of the arm but the arm won't attach to the bones.

[image]

Could you explain in super layman terms since I'm an absolute beginner to Blender?

[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/180x-BUzitQPbeXgw6h8eo8G9onhJgIph/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Would you mind explaining your process? You should have all the bones for your rig created before attaching it to a mesh. At least that's the way I do it.

Comment: Hello, as user123546863 says you should prepare the whole armature and the whole mesh before parenting, also you need to choose a way of parenting, if you want to parent With Automatic Weight, only create one object with all your meshes (or with one mesh). Delete all the keyframes you've created, apply the scales, make sure that the normals are correctly oriented. At last, try to stay as low poly as possible, use the Subdivision Surface modifier to rounf the shape, unless you have good reason to use a high-poly mesh. Maybe you should follow some tutorials on basic riggings.

Comment: @moonboots, thanks for your suggestions! I created the hand's armature and then extended it to the rest of the arm - which I understand now is a bad practice. As you said, I'll first create the entire skeleton first and then parent to my object. 

I parented the armature using automatic weight. But I have multiple objects here, as you can see in the image, and the shoes are disconnected from the body of the character. Can you please tell me how I should be parenting in this case?

Here is the reference for the character I've picked up: 
https://www.agorapulse.com/

Comment: @user123546863 Thanks for your suggestion! I didn't make all the bones properly before rigging, like you said, so I'll work on this first.

Comment: no problems. I'll go a head and post an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

As I and moonboots have suggested, you should have your entire skeleton complete before binding it to a mesh. Once your skeleton is complete you can parent it with automatic weights using ctrl+p. I don't like giving down votes unless questions are particularly bad. However, I should mention that there are vast amounts of beginner rigging tutorials on youtube and that you should try and research these things before asking questions.